# ЧПУ с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

У меня есть правило htaccess для одного параметра в УРЛ

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^www\.].*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-/]+)/?$ ?cat=$1 [L]
```

Подскажите как прописать аналогичное правило для другого параметра к примеру ?item=6

эти параметры могут склеиваются в ссылке, но так же могут быть по одиночке.

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел решение

вот ссылка на сайте которую я формирую из полей в БД 
 http://site.ru/dlya-doma/televizori/page-3/

```
<?php

echo"<a href='http://site.ru/".$row['catalog']."/".$row['tovar']."/page-".$paginator_num." '></a>

?>
```

вот правила .htaccess

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/=\.*]+)/$ ?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/=\.*]+)/([^/=\.*]+)/$ ?cat=$1&item=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/=\.*]+)/([^/=\.*]+)/page-([0-9]+)/$ ?cat=$1&item=$2&page=$3
```

и не смотря что у меня ссылка вида http://site.ru/dlya-doma/televizori/page-3/
я получаю нужные мне для работы параметры GET из данной ссылки

```
<?php
    $_GET['cat']=dlya-doma
    $_GET['item']=televizori
    $_GET['page']=3
?>
```